# градиент на весь документ

Tags: html, css

Сделал фон страницы цветами градиента, но внизу осталось немножко места не покрашенным.

не подскажете, в чем у меня проблема?

```
html, body {
       height: 100%;
}
body {
    background: linear-gradient(to left bottom, #1A0C2A, #907375) no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Нужен весь код. Ошибка видимо в другом месте.

Comment: весь код css - a  ?

Comment: Тут можете нажать Ctrl+M или кнопка "Фрагмент кода" и вставить css\html чтоб можно было тут увидеть код и его результат либо codepen или просто ссылку на проект в интернете чтоб увидеть в живую что не так работает и пофиксить это

Comment: для `html, body` добавьте `padding: 0` и `margin: 0`

Comment: @carcinogen75 не помогло

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LgNzqX

здесь вопще много не  крашется,

но у меня, в документе только немножко в самом внизу остается не покрашенным

Comment: ничего не закешировалось?? у меня сработал мой вариант - https://ibb.co/b5xHzK

Comment: @carcinogen75 нет, все остался как есть.. просто маржини исчезли  и все

Comment: вот https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JmXOpQ убери из `html, body` body

Comment: OOO так уже помогло...спасибо огромое @carcinogen75 !!!!... спасибо